# Firefox 33 and jquery bug?

Tags: jquery, firefox

Anyone else seeing issues with Firefox 33 and jquery event binding?

Our sites are using jquery (jquery-1.8.3) with normal event bindings like clicks on elements like this:

```
$( ".elementOnPage" ).click( function() {
    console.log('elementOnPage clicked');
});
```

They work for a while but then all of a sudden they stop working. Refreshing the page does nothing nor does clearing cache.

I have to exit Firefox and restart it. No problems in any other browsers.

This happened two Firefox updates ago, I let it slide figuring the next patch would fix it but its still broken in 33.1.1 so I think 33.1.0 is where it was introduced but not positive.

Reproduction steps:

1. Start Firefox 33+
2. Browse to a site that uses jquery
3. Use it for a while
4. All of a sudden bound clicks stop working. Breakpoints aren't even hit. Its like it looses all the bindings. Even across multiple tabs, and totally different website. Normal hyperlinks on a page still work but nothing bound with jquery does. I can see the state of the element change (like button press state) but the bound event never triggers).

At this point you must exit Firefox and restart then all is well until it stops again. No triggers that cause it to stop that I can identify.

I've only found one other person reporting this and it was in [Mozillazine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=2888969), no mention in actual Firefox bug system that I can find.

Comment: Perhaps make a minimal test case - perhaps a button that increments a counter so that it's clear when it stops working.

Comment: Its not a specific element that does it. It just stops working for anything that has a binding. Unfortunately I had to revert to Firefox 32 because I have a project deadline to meet. Doesn't happen there.

Comment: If you believe this to be an actual bug in FF33, make a minimal test case on jsfiddle.net and report it to bugzilla

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me every day. Firefox 33.1 will work for a little while, and then hovering and other jQuery events just stop working. Chrome still works with no problem. I'm worried one of our clients will update Firefox and notice their sites don't work anymore.